# Can't read the text file in metro apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I can read the text file for first time. when i try to read the same text file next time, it quit the function and return null value.

```
    static string configData = "";
    async public void readtextFile(string folder, string file)
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(folder);
        StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
        configData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
    }
```

Please suggest me, how to resolve this issue..

Thanks
SheikAbdullah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't forget that `readtextFile` is an asynchronous method. When you call it, it actually returns when it reaches the first `await`, so at this point `configData` is not set yet. You should return the value from the method, and await the method:

```
async public Task<string> readtextFile(string folder, string file)
{
    StorageFolder storageFolder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(folder);
    StorageFile storageFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync(file);
    string configData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);
    return configData;
}

...

string configData = await readTextFile(folder, file);
```

Even if you want to store `configData` in a field, you still need to `await readtextFile` before you read the value.