# FileIO.ReadTextAsync returns "Empty String". Error while writing xml fil

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

`FileIO.ReadTextAsync` always returns empty string ("") in Windows 8 application. Am working on Universal application and to note is that, `FileIO.ReadTextAsync` returns string when deploying in Windows Phone application but returns empty string in Windows 8 application? Here is my code.

```
async Task<string> LoadStatus(String listFileName)
{
    StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(listFileName);
    string configData = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(localFile);
    return configData;
}
```

And am calling this function as,

```
string result = await LoadStatus(AppConstants.VeryHappyStatusListName);
```

And listFileName is "**FileName.xml**".

I have gone through these ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12362553/how-to-get-return-value-synchronously-using-readtextasyncstoragefile-file-in-w) and [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10512355/cant-read-the-text-file-in-metro-apps)) posts and followed the same procedure but still returns null?

**Also one thing to note that, Am getting error while writing data. Sometime it writes data perfectly and sometimes i get error while writing.**

Here is my **save to storage** method.

```
async public void SaveStatus(List<Datum> list, String listFileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string localData = ObjectSerializer<List<Datum>>.ToXml(list);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(localData))
                {
                    StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(listFileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

                    if (localFile != null)
                    {
                        //await Task.Delay(3000);
                        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(localFile, localData);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                DebugPrint(ex.Message.ToString());
                DebugPrintLocation("SaveStaus", "SessionStorage");
            }
        }
```

Am following this link : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinStoreAppSaveCollection-bed5d6e6

Also important thing to note that, if I check each line using breakpoints everything goes fine. I can able to save large list and retrieve. But couldn't control without breakpoints.

Comment: Open the file in Notepad (localFile.Path) to check if it is really an empty file?

Comment: @kennyzx Yeah, I will check that. But how could it run well in Windows Phone. Same code for both platforms but I dont know why it returns empty string

Comment: How are you including the file in the projects?  Is it different?

Comment: No, Its normal Save method. I just followed the below link and completed. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWinStoreAppSaveCollection-bed5d6e6
Interesting thing to note here is that, am getting the response when my internet connection is fast in Windows 8 while saving the value.

Comment: StorageFile localFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("localData.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);  This line in Save function returns string value when i have proper net connection and returns null when slow connection. And everything is working fine in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my Windows 8 apps and it works well:

```
    public async void ReadTextFile(string cFile)
    {
        var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
        var file = await folder.GetFileAsync(cFile);
        var read = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(file);
        CurrentFileBuffer = read;
    }
```

Comment: I just wanna say you one thing that, I get problem during writing list in Storage?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for writing. It is also probably a good idea to explain which error you get exactly when you post a question.

```
public async Task WriteDataToFileAsync(string fileName, string content)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(content);
    var folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
    var file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
    {
        await s.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: file doesn't contain OpenStreamForWriteAsync() method. Am working on Universal App